# Is there a way to directly see the number of combinations? (other than as $n\mathrm{C}r = n\mathrm{P}r/n!$)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, combinations, visualization

It seems there should be a way to "directly" determine the number of distinct subsets of a given size $r$ possible using $n$ distinct elements, i.e. number of combinations.

The usual way to think about it is to first determine the number of distinct ordered lists of a size $r$ using $n$ distinct elements (i.e. number of permutations, $n\mathrm{P}r = \frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$), and because that includes different orderings of the same elements, then divide by $r!$ (i.e. the number of permutations of those $r$ elements), giving $n\mathrm{C}r = \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$.

> For example, given $6$ elements $a,b,c,d,e,f$, the number of combinations of $3$ of them is the number of permutations of $3$ of them ($6\times 5\times 4 = 120$, or $6\mathrm{P}4 = \frac{6!}{(6-3)!}$). But this includes $abc, acb, bac, bca, cab, cba$ as distinct elements (because distincting orderings of the same three elements). So we divide by the number of ways of arranging $3$ elements (i.e. their permutations, which is $3! = 6$; or using the formula, $ 3\mathrm{P}3 = \frac{3!}{(3-3)!} $ ), which gives $120/6 = 20$.

Is there a way to build up the number of distinct subset directly, instead of working out permutations and then cancelling out the different orderings later?

**Thoughts**
I think, if there is a "direct" way to think about it, it will be much more complex than this one --- or the above approach wouldn't be taught.

By "direct", I mean something like building a subset (a combination) step by step. But when I do that naively, it includes subsets with their elements in a different order (as in the above): a permutation, not a combination.

A decision tree would show which paths result in the same elements included at different levels. But how to eliminate those from start (instead of cancelling them out later)?

Perhaps it's related to the size of a "powerset", the set of all subsets?

BTW: I realize that any "direct" calculation would be equivalent to the standard one above; I really mean a way to thinking about it/conceptualize it as direct, rather then doing permutations first, then accounting for ordering.

*EDIT* another way to think of it is as how many $n$ digit binary numbers (including leading $0$'s) have $r$ $1$'s. The $n$ digit binary number is a bitfield (each position represents one of $n$ elements, value of $1$ means it is in the subset, $0$ means it is not); the number of $1$'s ($r$) is how many are in the subset.

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: This is a comment rather than an answer because I haven't thought very deeply about it, but any method for ranking and unranking combinations would give a bijection between $\{1, \ldots, {n \choose k}\}$ and the $k$-subsets of $\{1, \ldots, n\}$, and could therefore be thought of as a method of "directly constructing combinations": see https://computationalcombinatorics.wordpress.com/2012/09/10/ranking-and-unranking-of-combinations-and-permutations/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely! You can build a decision tree out of $_n C _r$ via the identity
$$_n C _r = _{n-1}C_r + _{n-1}C_{r-1}.$$
We set out to select a subset $S \subseteq \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ of size $r$. Here's the recursive decision tree:

- If $n  \in S$, then we take $S = \{n\} \cup T$, where $T \subseteq \{1, 2, \ldots, n-1\}$ is a subset of size $r-1$.
- Otherwise, we take $S = T$, where $T \subseteq \{1, 2, \ldots, n-1\}$ is a subset of size $r$.

Comment: Ah, this is also *Pascal's Triangle*, adding the two above. I don't yet see why that identity is true, but it's progress, and I'd better go one step at a time. Thanks!

Comment: This is so cool! Thanks for this.

Comment: @hyperpallium This decision tree shows you why Pascal's identity is true!

Comment: Oh I see: you separate them into those with element $n$ and those without. For those with element $n$, you remove it from each one, so they cannot have element $n$ and have one fewer elements, so there are $_{n-1}C_{r-1}$ of them. Those without element $n$ also cannot have element $n$ but are still size $r$, so there are $_{n-1}C_r$ of them. Just as you said!